# Is it possible to build a Console app that does not display a console Window when double-clicked?

Tags: .net, windows, console, console-application

> Related:
>   [Should I include a command line mode in my applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117275/should-i-include-a-command-line-mode-in-my-applications)
>   [How to grab parent process standard output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377911/how-to-grab-parent-process-standard-output)
>   [Can a console application detect if it has been run from Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510805)

I want to build a console app, that is normally run from the command line.

But, when it is double clicked from within Explorer (as opposed to being run from a cmd.exe prompt) then I'd like the program to NOT display a console window.

I want to avoid this:

[image]

Is it possible?

**EDIT** I guess another way to ask it is, *is it possible for a program to know how it was invoked - whether by double-click or by command line* ?

I'm working in .NET, on Windows.

**EDIT 2:** From [this *Old New Thing* blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/01/01/9259142.aspx) I learned some good stuff.  Here's what I know now...

In Windows, EXE files are marked as either GUI or non-GUI. With csc.exe, this is selected with `/target:winexe` or `/target:exe`. Before the first instruction in the process executes, the Windows kernel sets up the execution environment. At that moment, if the EXE is marked GUI, the kernel sets the stdin/stdout for the process to NULL, and if non-GUI (command-line) the kernel creates a console and sets the stdin/stdout for the process to that console.

When launching the process, if there is no stdin/stdout (== `/target:winexe`), then the call immediately returns.  So, launching a gui app from a cmd.exe, you will immediately get your cmd prompt back.  If there is a stdin/stdout, and if run from cmd.exe, then the parent cmd.exe waits for process exit.

The "immediate return" is important because if you code a GUI app to attach to its parent's console, you will be able to do console.writeline, etc.  But the cmd.exe prompt is active. The user can type new commands, start a new process, and so on.  In other words, from a winexe, simply attaching to the parent console with `AttachConsole(-1)` will not "turn it into" a console app.

---

At this point I think the only way to allow an app to use the console if it is invoked from cmd.exe, and NOT use it if it is double-clicked, is to define the exe as a regular console exe (`/target:exe`), and *hide the window* on startup if appropriate.  You still get a console window appearing briefly.

I still haven't figured how to know whether it was launched from explorer or cmd.exe, but I'm getting closer..

---

**ANSWERS**

It is not possible to build a console app that does not display a console window.

It *is possible* to build a console app that hides its window very quickly, but not so quickly that it is as if the window never appears.

Now, to determine whether a console app was launched from explorer, some have suggested to look at the console it is running in
(from [mgb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528152/is-it-possible-to-build-a-console-app-that-does-not-display-a-console-window-when/1528271#1528271),  and [KB article 99115](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99115))  :

```
  int left = Console.CursorLeft;
  int top = Console.CursorTop;
  bool ProcessWasRunFromExplorer = (left==0 && top==0);
```

This tells you if the process was launched in its own console, but not whether it was explorer.  A double click in explorer would do this, but also a Start.Process() from within an app would do the same thing.

If you want to treat those situations differently, use this to learn the name of the parent process:

```
  System.Console.WriteLine("Process id: {0}", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
  string name = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName ;
  System.Console.WriteLine("Process name: {0}", name);
  PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Creating Process Id", name);
  Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)pc.RawValue);
  System.Console.WriteLine("Parent Process id: {0}", p.Id);
  System.Console.WriteLine("Parent Process name: {0}", p.ProcessName);

  // p.ProcessName == "cmd" or "Explorer" etc
```

To hide the window quickly after the process is launched, use this:

```
  private static readonly int SW_HIDE= 0;

  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern Boolean ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);

  ....
  {
    IntPtr myHandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
    ShowWindow(myHandle, SW_HIDE);
  }
```

If you produce a `winexe` (a WinForms app), and optionally attach to the parent console when appropriate with `AttachConsole(-1)`, you do not get the equivalent of a regular console app. For a winexe, the parent process (like cmd.exe) will return to the command prompt immediately after starting a GUI application. In other words, the command prompt is active and ready for input while the just-launched process may be emitting output. This is confusing and is probably useful only for debugging winforms apps.

This worked for me.

Comment: What would you like it to do instead?

Comment: The test to determine if the program was started in its own console is wrong. Entering `cls & program.exe` at the command line will erroneously state that the program was started in its own console. You could do the same thing from a batch file. Likely there are other ways to defeat the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Can a Win32 console application detect if it has been run from the explorer or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510805/can-a-win32-console-application-detect-if-it-has-been-run-from-the-explorer-or-no)

Or I think the official way is to check the parent process is cmd.exe or explorer.exe

Answer (score 7):

So, I've written tools with both a GUI and a CLI. The hard part was figuring out which one to open - in our case, though, the CLI version had required parameters, so I just opened the GUI if there weren't any parameters. Then, if they did want a console, call a function that looks something like:

```
private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;
private const int ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE = 6;
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool AllocConsole();
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool FreeConsole();

private static bool StartConsole()
{
  if (!AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)) // try connecting to an existing console  
  {  
      if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE) // we don't have a console yet  
      {  
          if (!AllocConsole()) // couldn't create a new console, either  
              return false;  
      }
      else
          return false; // some other error
  }
  return true;
}
```

Returns whether the console was created. Don't forget to FreeConsole() when you're done!

In our case, of course, if we don't create a console, we create a GUI. It'd be just as easy to create either a console or *no* UI, though.

EDIT: That totally didn't answer the question in the edit that wasn't there when I started writing that, of course. Other than that our hack was just checking whether it was called with command-line parameters or not.

Comment: This is helpful - it lets me create a console app or not at runtime. The key thing is, how to determine whether a console is present. I think that is AttachConsole(-1), but even when that returns 0, I don't know how to suppress the console when it is not present. I'll have to try a few things. thanks

Answer (score 6):

Just build it as a Windows Forms app, but don't give it a GUI. Unfortunately then you won't get any console output when it's run from the command line either... is that a problem?

Comment: Thinking about this a little more, I don't think this will work. I know how to make an EXE either a console app or a WinForms app at runtime, using pinvoke on AttachConsole(). But I don't know how to determine when to make it a console app or a Winforms app. I don't know how to detect if it was lauched by a double-click in explorer, or launched from a console window.

Comment: Why not use a command line argument to select console display mode? That way when run from Explorer, it won't have one; unless you create a shortcut and add the argument there - allowing you to have both with and without console launches from Explorer.

Comment: That doesn't quite do it for me. First because I don't want the behavior to be command-line selectable. I want it to be automatic.  Second because using the parent's console isn't the same as being a regular console app. See the blog post from Old New Thing http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/01/01/9259142.aspx
for an explanation of why.

Comment: How about this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66607616/463571

Comment: @AntonNorko: That basically *is* the solution I gave in 2009.

Answer (score 3):

You can build Windows App which does not have a console window:

Go to project properties > Application and change output type from **Console** to **Windows Application**.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Would this be more like a Service then?

OR

What About a Windows Forms application that doesn't have a visible form?  It would still show up in the Task Manager Processes list.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read everything thru, but did this (a little while ago, more testing needed):

```
DWORD proc[2],procsfound=GetConsoleProcessList(proc,ELEMS(proc));
if (procsfound>1)
// I'm started as a command in cmd.exe
else
// started from explorer or other non-console parent
```

IFF there's more than one proc attached, I need to restore the console which I manipulated, otherwise not.
May be useful, at least it's simplicity itself.
Start the code from VS will yield a single attached proces, running it from commandprompt did activate the branch to clean up my mess.
Btw, a console launched from explorer or other non-console app will have a zero-length title?